# use child graphql resolver inside any parent resolver - resolver chaining

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-server, resolver

Let's say I have an author with different books.
I can either fetch a book alone, or fetch an author with its books.

```
type Query {
  author(authorId: ID!): Author
  book(bookId: ID!): Book
}

type Author {
  books: [Book!]!
}

type Book {
  title: String!
}
```

The book can already resolve by himself:

```js
// book-resolver.js
{
  // single source of truth for book resolving
  Book: {
    title: (_, {bookId}) => fetchBookTitleByBookId(bookId)
  }
}
```

##### **How can I reuse the book resolver in the Author's resolver? I would like to avoid rewriting it:**

```js
// author-resolver.js
{
  Author: {
    books: (_, {authorId}) => {
      const bookIds = fetchBookIdsByAuthorId(authorId)
    
      return {
        // here I'm duplicating logic. Can I avoid it?
        books: bookIds.map(bookId => ({
          title: fetchBookTitleByBookId(bookId)
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I think that creating an utility function (e.g. `fetchBook(id)`) and using it everywhere wouldn't match the "paradigm" of resolver chaining.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it is a bad idea to query so many items singularly, but if you must do so, you can use [Apollo resolver chains](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/resolvers/#resolver-chains)

Keep in mind thad by doing so, you will call  `fetchBookTitleByBookId(bookId)` n times (where n is the number of books) + `fetchBookIdsByAuthorId(authorId)` once. See this answer for more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/60832838/10909317

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm aware of resolver chains and dedupe/caching, but I'm wondering, how to avoid rewriting the same resolver for Author.books & Book alone.

Comment: @BiasInput you write `books: bookIds.map(bookId => ({bookId}))` and nothing else. The `Book.title` field resolver is automatically called on every `{bookId}` object.

Comment: By returning `[{bookId}]` from `Author.books`, isn't it passed by the `parent` arg, instead of the `args` arg? Because the `Book.title` resolver isn't relying on a parent arg.